Root cause continuous network interface toggles
I'm a network driver developer and I stumbled upon an issue for which I'd be thankful to get some guidance.
On AWS and Ubuntu 24.04 , after reloading the network driver (ena), the interface takes a considerable time to be brought up again with an ip.
Digging into the journal I see the same pattern repeating itself:
Sep 05 18:13:46 ip-172-31-7-249 kernel: ena 0000:00:05.0 ens5: ena_up
...
Sep 05 18:13:46 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: Link UP
Sep 05 18:13:46 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: Gained carrier
Sep 05 18:13:46 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23065]: dhcpcd-10.0.6 starting
Sep 05 18:13:46 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23068]: DUID 00:01:00:01:2e:6c:35:33:02:16:5c:16:1f:65
Sep 05 18:13:46 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23068]: ens5: IAID 5c:16:1f:65
Sep 05 18:13:47 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: Gained IPv6LL
Sep 05 18:13:48 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23068]: ens5: rebinding lease of 172.31.7.249
Sep 05 18:13:48 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23068]: ens5: leased 172.31.7.249 for 3600 seconds
Sep 05 18:13:48 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23068]: ens5: adding route to 172.31.0.0/20
Sep 05 18:13:48 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23068]: ens5: adding default route via 172.31.0.1
Sep 05 18:13:48 ip-172-31-7-249 kernel: ena 0000:00:05.0 ens5: ena_close, invoked by: 23085
Sep 05 18:13:48 ip-172-31-7-249 kernel: ena 0000:00:05.0 ens5: ena_down
Sep 05 18:13:48 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: Link DOWN
Sep 05 18:13:48 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: Lost carrier
...
Sep 05 18:13:58 ip-172-31-7-249 kernel: ena 0000:00:05.0 ens5: ena_up
...
Sep 05 18:13:58 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: Link UP
Sep 05 18:13:58 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: Gained carrier
Sep 05 18:13:58 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23092]: dhcpcd-10.0.6 starting
Sep 05 18:13:58 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23095]: DUID 00:01:00:01:2e:6c:35:33:02:16:5c:16:1f:65
Sep 05 18:13:58 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23095]: ens5: IAID 5c:16:1f:65
Sep 05 18:13:58 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: DHCPv4 address 172.31.7.249/20, gateway 172.31.0.1 acquired from 172.31.0.1
...
Sep 05 18:13:58 ip-172-31-7-249 chronyd[1433]: Source 169.254.169.123 online
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23095]: ens5: rebinding lease of 172.31.7.249
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23095]: ens5: leased 172.31.7.249 for 3600 seconds
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23095]: ens5: adding route to 172.31.0.0/20
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23095]: ens5: adding default route via 172.31.0.1
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23095]: ens5: pid 0 deleted route to 172.31.0.0/20
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 dhcpcd[23095]: control command: /usr/sbin/dhcpcd --dumplease --ipv4only ens5
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 kernel: ena 0000:00:05.0 ens5: ena_close, invoked by: 23111
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 kernel: ena 0000:00:05.0 ens5: ena_down
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: Link DOWN
Sep 05 18:13:59 ip-172-31-7-249 systemd-networkd[1123]: ens5: Lost carrier

So the sequence is :

something asks the driver to bring the interface up
networkd notices link change and invokes dhcpcd
dhcp gets correct configuration
right after that, something asks the driver to bring down the interface

dumping the callstack from the driver only reveals that the the interface is brought down by a userspace syscall, but I can't tell what process requested it (can't find the pid that is used when the driver's interface down command is executing).
If anyone knows any tools to retrieve this information it'd would also provide me with great help.
Eventually, the same log messages appear, but without invoking dhcpcd, and this time the interface isn't brought down and the network stabilizes. This happens after ~5 minutes of the repeated logs above.
So my main question is whether anyone here is familiar enough with systemd-networkd to explain this behavior. As far as I'm aware the driver isn't advertising any link problems (I'm one of the developers of the driver) and isn't bringing the carrier down.

Is this AWS machine supposed to be a DHCP server rather than a client of AWS's native DHCP service?  None of my AWS machines have dhcpd installed and they talk to the AWS DHCP service perfectly fine without it.  (they use dhclient or something similar instead)

This is a vanilla Ubuntu 24.04 ARM instance. It uses dhcpcd which is a DHCP client.
It also reproduced very easily. Just bringup an Ubuntu 24.04 ARM instance, and run sudo modprobe -r ena && sudo modprobe ena. The network will take several minutes to come back.
The instance clearly has some lack of support for driver toggle operations, I'm trying to root cause why

When I check the 24.04 packages at packages.ubuntu.com for files ending in 'dhcpd' the ones that come up are packages for DHCP servers rather than clients.  And this is how it's been since 8.04.  This is why I asked.
